# If an integer $k$ is a divisor of an integer $n$, then $\frac{n}{k}$ is also a divisor of $n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A lot of these number theory ideas are popping up in my study of cyclic groups. 
In particular, in a note I came across.

It is mentioned that:

> If an integer $k$ is a divisor of an integer $n$, then $n/k$ is also a divisor of $n$.

Could someone be kind enough to give me an explanation as to why this is generally true?

Comment: Not true. Let $k=6$, $n=3$, for instance.

Comment: Do you mean divisor of $k$?

Comment: I think what you wanted to say was: if $k$ is a divisor of $n$, then $n/k$ is also a divisor of $n$.

Comment: @AnuragA Thank you. That's it.

Comment: @Mathematicing in  that case just observe that $n=k\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)$. Since $k$ is a divisor then that means $\frac{n}{k}$ is an integer and also a divisor of $n$..

Comment: Only for $n \ge k$

Comment: That's obviously , because of their product is $n$

Comment: @openspace $n \geq k$ is not a necessary condition. For example, $n=-10$ and $k=5$. Perhaps you want to say $|n| \geq k$, but that would be trivially true because $k$ divides $n$.

Comment: @AnuragA yeah , that's right

Answer (score 1):

$k$ divides $n$.

Let $n$=$kc$, where $c$ is an integer, from the definition of divisibiltiy.

Now, what else can you say from definition of divisibility?. You can say that $c$ divides $n$, since $k$ is an integer too. But $c=\frac{n}{k}$